# On mouse over event reloads the flash in Firefox 7

Tags: html, firefox, browser, onmouseover

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="feed-item" style="position:relative;" id="feed-611" onmouseover="showDelete()" onmouseout="hideDelete()">
<div class="feed-avatar">
    AVATAR
</div>
<div class="feed-content">
    CONTENTS
</div>
<div class="feed-attachment-video-holder" id="feed-attachment-video-holder611">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="player611" data="http://www.youtube.com/e/bRU1XRuC6DI?enablejsapi=1&amp;version=3&amp;playerapiid=611" width="570" height="350"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></object>
</div>
```

It works fine in IE and Chrome but in Firefox 3,6 and 7 when The mouse enters the feed-item the youtube player reloads and the video starts again. The css for the hover effect is something like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1.0em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 1.0em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
box-shadow:0 0 1.0em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.3);
position:relative;
```

Is this a known problem and do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Just making sure: You're aware that "feed-item"'s div is never closed in your sample... So it's unclear where it terminates. The z-index could be altered by handling of unclosed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox has various bugs which cause Flash object reloads. For example, if you **change** the values of **display, position, or overflow** css properties dynamically on the container of a flash movie, the flash movie will reload (see [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268)). IFAIK, you can't fix this problem by yourself, please wait for Mozilla :(

Back to your code, why you need to change video container position to `relative` when the mouse enter the `feed-item`? Remove `position:relative;` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you could use a :hover{} css meathod to show the control by making the visability to show?
If you want to use jQuery, you could use:

```
$(".control").hover(function(){
$("div-with-flash") .html(newContent); 
});
```

Is that close to what you want?